# Google App Script - Update slides in "present" mode, automatically behind the scenes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-slides

I have a Google Slide Presentation, which in that I retrieve my Google Calendar information via *AppScript* and inject them into different slides. I have a trigger also set to do this every 5 minutes automatically!

All is fine! The only issue is that I want to share it with the team in present (preview) mode, but slides don't get updated in each iteration of trigger run... they just get updated in "edit" mode!

Is there any way to force this update on the slides on Present mode as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's currently not possible to run code in Presentation mode, as it doesn't load most of the Slide's interface, therefore Apps Script is not loaded either. It's like a "view" mode.

There is a Feature Request in [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760981) asking for this. You can click on the star next to the issue number to receive updates and to give more priority to the Request.